# Thinkpad T61 - How to disable rescue and recovery backup and recover the disk space

Tags: windows, backup, thinkpad

I've got a thinkpad T61, and little did I realize it was backing up my computer onto the same hard drive.  My 80G hard drive is essentially cut in half b/c it filled up the other half with "backups".

I don't care about the backups, I want the disk space back.

Anyone know how to do this?

When I run the 'Rescue and Recovery' preferences, I see no control over how much space it will use.  The only other pane allows me to "customize" what files get backed up (or not), which doesn't help because the space is already used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found how to do this.  The hard part was finding where to start.  You need to find the `Rescue and Recovery` application, which for me was in the `Start` menu.

```
Start menu
    Run "ThinkVantage Productivity Center"
       Menu "ThinkVantage Technologies"
           > "Rescue and Recovery"
```

## Disable Backups

```
Manage Settings
    Set schedule and preferences

In popup
    Uncheck the 'Schedule your backups` checkbox
    Press `OK` button
```

## Recover Space

```
Advanced
    Delete Backups

In popup
   Select the backups you wish to delete.
   Press `Delete` button
```

Comment: I spent a long time finding the Advanced menu referred to above. In "Enhanced Backup and Restore" there is a link in the lower left corner called "Launch advanced Rescue and Recovery". In the window that appears, there is an "Advanced" menu in the very top of the window. I didn't notice it because it's the only window that has a menu there.

Answer (score 3):

I think Thinkpad's use a hidden partition for the Rescue and Recovery. You can use the FOSS software GParted (available as a Live CD) to remove that partition and merge the space back to your main partition.

Be careful when doing anything that impacts your partitions and back up your data first.

Comment: Backup your entire physical disk using Clonezilla first.  Then you'll be safe.